# Double click in DataGridView row and display columns in another DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So, I am trying to build a code where I could be able to after click F1 it will display in a new form a `datagridview` depending on the `textbox`. Then I want to double click in that row and display in the main `datagridview` what I selected into the new form `datagridview`. This is the code I got:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
    this.Hide();
    frmPrincipal frm = new frmPrincipal();

    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConnP);
        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT RTRIM(CL.Cargs) AS 'Cargs', RTRIM(S.Abvs) AS 'Abvs',  RTRIM(CL.Linha) AS 'Linha', RTRIM(CL.Qty) AS 'Quantity'
                             FROM CargsCab CC (NOLOCK)
                             INNER JOIN CargsLin CL (NOLOCK) ON CC.Cargs = CL.Cargs
                             INNER JOIN Stock S (NOLOCK) ON CL.Code = S.Code
                             INNER JOIN Marks M (NOLOCK) ON S.Marks = M.Marks
                             WHERE CC.Date >= GETDATE() - 120 AND CL.State NOT IN ('F', 'A') AND S.TypeEmb = 'P' 
                             AND CC.Type = 'OCS' AND CL.Cargs LIKE '%" + dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "%' ORDER BY CL.Cargs, S.Marks DESC, S.Abvs", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds, "CargCab");
        da.Fill(ds, "CargLin");
        da.Fill(ds, "Stock");
        da.Fill(ds, "Mark");

        frm.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["CargCab"].DefaultView;
        frm.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["CargLin"].DefaultView;
        frm.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Stock"].DefaultView;
        frm.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Mark"].DefaultView;

        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error\nDetalhes: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, you wanna get selected data from popup Form back to your main form. 
I prefer doing it in following way:

On main form when you are creating new Form, attach to it event handler

```
FormClosing
```

On that event call method that you need to add in your new form 
for example

```
var selectedData= MyForm.GetData();
```

This is available because form is still closing and not yet disposed.

Your method "GetData" has to collect selected data form datagridView of course.
This was covered many times on stackoverflow so you will find this easily.

Corrected way:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Form2 f2;
    private obj returnedData;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         f2 = new Form2();
        f2.FormClosing += F_FormClosing;
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void F_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.returnedData = f2.GetData();  //clicked data is returned to your main form, do what you want with it
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private List<obj> list;
    private obj selectedData;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        data.CellDoubleClick += DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick;

        list = new List<obj>();
        data.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        list.Add(new obj() { a = "abc1", b = "abc2" });
        list.Add(new obj() { a = "cda1", b = "cda2" });
        data.DataSource = list;



    }



    internal obj GetData()
    {
        return selectedData;
    }

    private void DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        selectedData = list.ElementAt(e.RowIndex);

        this.Close();
    }

}

internal class obj
{
    [DisplayName("aaa")]
    public string a { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("bbb")]
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What about the DataGridView row double click?

Comment: DataGridView does not have RowDoubleClick event so you can use CellDoubleClick

  private void DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var ddd = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        }

Comment: DataGridViewCellEventArgs contains RowIndex. If your dataGridView has datasource you can easily get clicked item.

Comment: Where do I put this code : var selectedData= MyForm.GetData(); in the frmPrincipal?

Comment: You put that code inside event handler of FormClosing event.

Comment: And this handler you put inside your main form from which you call second form (MyForm)

Comment: Inside of the main form FormClosing event?

Comment: But you deal with this event inside MainForm.

Comment: The event CellDoubleClick is inside of the second DGV

Comment: Yes, and as I undestand you want to doubleClick on row, then inside your second window CellDoubleClick event would be called. Then you do what needs to be done (something you wrote in your main question) and calls this.Close(); Then your second window is closing but this rises event FormClosing on the main form, you deal with returned data and second form can close entirely. Then you have your clicked data in your main window.

Comment: I've understand the theory, I just do not know what would be the code

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4H-gdv-vRD2RktBWkdJYllOZkU/view?usp=sharing

here is sample project

Comment: datagridView does not show values properly but that was not an objective

Comment: What I should put inside of the GetData method?

Comment: Whatever you want to return from this second Form. If you want you can return whole DataObject used to fill DataGridView in second Form and then add it to DataGridView in first Form (it types matches)

Comment: I cannot understand the code you sent me...Could you post it here?